# How to get the direction of the finger in android game

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a game with Android where I need to move a tile in all  directions. My question is how can I get the motion of the finger on the screen(right,left,top) using `getX()` and `getY()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `getHistoricalSize`, `getHistoricalX(int)` and `getHistoricalY(int)`.

When the finger is touching the screen, Android records the move positions and saves them. You can then call `getHistorySize` to get the number of motions recorded, and then call `getHistoricalX` and `getHistoricalY` with a parameter less that the history size to get the x/y at that history position.

So, for example, you can call `getHistoricalY` with a parameter that indicates that previous motion event, and then compare it to the current one. If the current one is bigger, then the finger is swiping down.

*Note*: Motion events recording applies *only* to `ACTION_MOVE`.